# /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?app=3 is returning random scripts tags

Tags: rest-api

I am so new to the world of API calling and apparently there is a script called in post API that is not letting me call them properly please see this link:

https://acciers.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?app=3

How can I remove this script tag from this file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window._nslDOMReady = function (callback) {
                if ( document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive" ) {
                    callback();
                } else {
                    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", callback );
                }
            };
            </script><script type='text/javascript' src='https://acciers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://acciers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2' id='jquery-migrate-js'></script>
```

Comment: do you have any plugins or themes that use the accronym NSL? This is usually caused by misbehaving or poorly coded plugins/themes that try to output scripts when a shortcode or function is called to avoid loading it on all pages. I tried loading the REST endpoint you mentioned but the content is just a login form. I'm assuming this is only visible to registered users. Disable plugins until the problem vanishes and then you will know which plugin is responsible

Comment: Thank you I found the plugin that is causing this issue, but this is the main plugin on my website which makes the profiles, and user base. I am not sure how I can prevent it from injecting that code. Its profile builder pro

Comment: you'll need to contact their support and report this as a bug